# Culling certain numbers from a List

Tags: python, list, compare

I have a series of variable lists inside a list, and I'm comparing it to another list.  I want, run through each list in aList, analyze each number and as soon its a match in bList, append that number to finalList.  I want to return the first match in other words and ignore future matches.  For Example:

```
aList = [[0,1],[8,9,4,5],[7,6,3,2]]
bList = [0,5,1,4]
finalList = [0,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

```
finalList = []

for sl in aList:
    for item in sl:
        if item in bList:
            finalList.append(item)
            break
```

To iterate with a single for loop you could use the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Comment: @ReutSharabani smells like premature optimization to me :)

Comment: Smells like the right data structure to me, but yeah if it's some one-off it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Also, if you were going to do that, you would want to create the set variable outside of the loop (since set creation is O(N)).

Comment: That's what I was aiming at, I just put the idea out there for you to add it if you want. Had it been that important I'd add my own answer.